# User ID not displaying in Google Analytics dashboard (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to link GA's User ID feature to my iOS app, but this doesn't seem to be working. From the documentation, I enables a User ID capable view (profile). Then, I set the userId field.

My code:
AppDelegate.m

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// You only need to set User ID on a tracker once. By setting it on the tracker, the ID will be
// sent with all subsequent hits.
[tracker set:@"&uid"
       value:@"userIDTest"];


// This hit will be sent with the User ID value and be visible in User-ID-enabled views (profiles).
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"User Test"            // Event category (required)
                                                      action:@"User Sign In"  // Event action (required)
                                                       label:nil              // Event label
                                                       value:nil] build]];    // Event value
```

However, in the analytics dashboard:

[image]

I can't seem to find one place where I can see the user id.

Comment: [Set up the User ID in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666)

Comment: Careful Jonny if Google find out you have usernames in your analytics data they will delete your entire account and all your data. See section 7 of the terms of use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot see the user id in Google Analytics at all. It's only there to unify data across devices. To view the user id, try adding a custom dimension which also records user id. Then you'll have access to view it in the interface.

More details on [adding custom dimensions to send user IDs to Google Analytics](https://davidsimpson.me/2014/04/20/tutorial-send-user-ids-google-analytics/).

Comment: I believe Ramos is referring to the view within GA noted here: http://cutroni.com/blog/2014/04/10/understanding-cross-device-measurement-and-the-user-id/ I also have the same issues.

Comment: Yes, but the User ID is *never* exposed in the Google Analytics interface. It is just used to unify user data across devices.

Comment: We're now in april with the user id feature rolled out. Is this still true? I don't see the coverage report they talk about in the documentation either. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123670?hl=en