# Query Google Analytics by User ID in custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Google Analytics v4 supports to query the reports like "User Explorer". I can query the list of userid in custom dimension. My request is:

```
{"reportRequests": [
          {
            "viewId": "xxxx",
            "includeEmptyRows": true,
            "dateRanges": [
              {
                "startDate": "2daysAgo",
                "endDate": "today"
              }
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "expression": "ga:sessions"
              },
              {
                "expression": "ga:avgSessionDuration"
              }
            ],
              "dimensions": [
                {
                  "name": "ga:dimension1"
                }
              ]

          }
        ]
}
```

I got the successful result. But I would like to query the detail of each userId. Something likes one individual Userid in a custom dimension same as "User Report" in Google Analytics. I googled around but did not have any luck. For example in here:

[Query Google Analytics by User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388047/query-google-analytics-by-user-id)

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/

I'm not sure that is there any support for the query individual userId like:
"filtersExpression": "ga:userId==abc"

Any recommendation is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using free version of GA querying by user id won't be possible unless you use custom dimension to store user id yourself.

Comment: Hi. I'm using custom dimension already. As you can see in my question, I can query a list of UserIds in custom dimension. The issue is, I'd like to query for one userId to get the whole detail of it. Any suggestion for that?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out from the custom dimension. 
try this `ga:dimension1==abc`

Comment: Have you tried to call this in GA request?! do you mean you can do sth like this in your request?! "dimensions": [
      {
        "name":"ga:dimension1==abc"
      }

Comment: @KennyTaiHuynh late reply but as zenab suggested you can supply a (custom) dimension value as filter, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters
Not sure why his answer was downvoted; should work.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass custom dimension like
"dimensions": [{ "name": "customUser:user_id_dimensions" }

here user_id_dimensions is custom dimension name.