# Google Analytics - Match UserID with my site's account ID

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, userid

Each of my registered clients have **an unique account ID** (eg: agent n°: 00173393).

I want to retrieve this information **through google analytics**... It's not a personal information and for statistics use only.

I implemented userID, but **how to match userID and the accounts IDs ?**

Is it possible to create a variable for the account ID number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the `account ID` as `User ID` as well? That way you would have a 1-to-1 match:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
  userId: accountId
});
```

Please note however that the `User ID` is not exposed back by Google Analytics. If you want to retrieve it, you need to save it inside a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en):

- Admin -> Property -> Custom Dimensions -> Create one with User scope
- Add custom dimension tracking to your code

For instance:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
  userId: accountId,
});
ga('set', 'cd1', accountId); // if it's custom dimension n1
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Then you can retrieve the `User ID` via the UI:

[image]

or the [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed process.. I'll test that.