# Google Analytics: Show User ID view report day by day

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

In GA dashboard, there is only report of number of active users in a day or week or year. If I need a report to collect which user id who visits my website, I have to click the range of the date day by day and export so many excels in order to combine them into one.

Is it possible to get a list of all user ids day by day.

Comment: Can you clarify which report you're talking about? Please give the full path (eg `Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Channels`) so there is no ambiguity

Comment: @Max It should be Audience -> User Explorer in UserId View.

Answer (score 1):

The [user id](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) field that you have submitted with your google analytics hit data is used for internal processing.  It is not something that you can actually see in either the google analytics website or the google analytics api.   Its used similar to the session id.

If you want to see it i recommend you try adding it as a custom dimension.

Comment: That means I have to pass a "new type" of user id by custom dimension? The previous data of user id are not available for extracting?

Comment: I double what @DaImTo said. Here is one way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886764/google-analytics-match-userid-with-my-sites-account-id/48904630#48904630